# How to remove array elements having same value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $near_by. The structure is like this:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [fname] => Test
            [lname] => 
            [image] => http://link//2.jpg
            [category_id] => 2
            [category_name_en] => Clinic
            [category_name_ar] => 
            [institute_rank] => 1
            [institute_rating] => 4.00
            [institute_review] => 1
            [total_institute] => 8
            [latitude] => 44.000984
            [longitude] => 106.76654
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 10
            [fname] => Test
            [lname] => 
            [image] => http://link//2.jpg
            [category_id] => 2
            [category_name_en] => Clinic
            [category_name_ar] => 
            [institute_rank] => 1
            [institute_rating] => 4.00
            [institute_review] => 1
            [total_institute] => 8
            [latitude] => 44.000984
            [longitude] => 106.76654
        )

)
```

**First Question:-**

I want to remove the duplicate elements. Like 0th element and 1st element are same, so I want to have a new array with only one from the duplicate values.

So I wrote this piece of code:-

```
$near_by_arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $near_by),SORT_REGULAR));
$near_by_final = array();
foreach($near_by_arr as $a)
{
    $near_by_final[] = $a;
}
```

However, the new array $near_by_final still contains the duplicate data. I have used this same code in another applictaion and it seems working there. What wrong am I doing now?

**Second question?**

Suppose the sub-array in each index are totally different in structure, but have a common index "user_id" which may contain same value. How can I retrieve only one element from the elements having same user_id value?

Say for example,

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 10
        [fname_en] => Test
        [lname_en] => 
        [image] => http://link//2.jpg
        [category_id] => 2
        [category_name_en] => Clinic
        [category_name_ar] => 
        [latitude] => 44.000984
        [longitude] => 106.76654
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 10
        [fname] => Test
        [lname] => 
        [image] => http://link//2.jpg
        [category_id] => 2
        [category_name_en] => Clinic
        [category_name_ar] => 
        [institute_rank] => 1
        [institute_rating] => 4.00
        [institute_review] => 1
        [total_institute] => 8
        [latitude] => 44.000984
        [longitude] => 106.76654
    )

 )
```

How can I have an array which will have the following structure?

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 10
        [fname_en] => Test
        [lname_en] => 
        [image] => http://link//2.jpg
        [category_id] => 2
        [category_name_en] => Clinic
        [category_name_ar] => 
        [latitude] => 44.000984
        [longitude] => 106.76654
    )
  )
```

Comment: *"Need urgent help"* - Please remove that.

Comment: *"Second question?"* - That made your question too broad. Ask one question at a time, that's how it works on Stack.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions (especially since you are an experienced user, and are expected to know this).

Answer (score 1):

Simply when creating array use associative array instead of indexed:

```
$near_by_arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $near_by),SORT_REGULAR));
$near_by_final = array();

foreach($near_by_arr as $a) {
    $near_by_final[$a['user_id']] = $a;

   /*
   OR to keep only first entry:

   if (!isset($near_by_final[$a['user_id']])) {
       $near_by_final[$a['user_id']] = $a;
   }
   */
}
```

If need it to be indexed any way:

```
foreach () {...}

$near_by_final = array_values($near_by_final);
```

Comment: But in your answer, we won't need to use array_map at all. For example:- `foreach($near_by as $a) {$near_by_final[$a['user_id']] = $a;}` would do the same. SInce we are using `$a['user_id']` as array index, then the value of that array index will get overwritten every time the loop encounters an user_id of same value.

Comment: @Saswat You need `array_map` because it unserialize your array and sorts it. And yes, it will be overwritten (unless you use commented code to keep only first occurrence). But if all values are the same, then there is no difference witch copy of data to use

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct, just use user_id as index instead of anto incremented index.

eq :

```
  $near_by_arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $near_by), SORT_REGULAR));
  $near_by_final = array();
  foreach ($near_by_arr as $a) {
       $near_by_final[$a['user_id']] = $a;
  }
```

Comment: But in your answer, we won't need to use array_map at all. For example:- `foreach($near_by as $a) {$near_by_final[$a['user_id']] = $a;}` would do the same.